# Why Systemd.timer got paused for sometime with OnCalendar

Tags: linux, systemd, timer

I am using Systemd.Timer to run my code every second. But the cronjob did not work well. It paused for every six or seven second. Like this:

```
Sun Jul 28 18:49:34 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:35 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:36 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:37 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:38 CST 2019 --- paused
Sun Jul 28 18:49:45 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:46 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:47 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:48 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:49 CST 2019 --- paused
Sun Jul 28 18:49:55 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:56 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:57 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:58 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:49:59 CST 2019 --- paused ...
Sun Jul 28 18:50:06 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:07 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:08 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:09 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:10 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:16 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:17 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:18 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:19 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:20 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:27 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:28 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:29 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:30 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:31 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:37 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:38 CST 2019
Sun Jul 28 18:50:39 CST 2019
```

How it was caused? Any solution could fix this out?

Here is the service:

```
#testTimer.service
[Unit]
Description=my description

[Service]
ExecStart=echo `date` >> /tmp/timer.log
```

Here is the timer:

```
#cal.timer
[Unit]
Description=my description

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:*:0/1
Unit=test.service
Persistent=yes
AccuracySec=1us

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the `systemctl list-timers --all`:

```
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Tue 2019-07-30 10:41:09 CST  459ms left    Tue 2019-07-30 10:41:08 CST  540ms ago    cal.timer                    testTimer.service
Tue 2019-07-30 15:14:52 CST  4h 33min left Mon 2019-07-29 15:14:52 CST  19h ago      systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Wed 2019-07-31 03:41:51 CST  17h left      Tue 2019-07-30 09:20:52 CST  1h 20min ago apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Wed 2019-07-31 06:13:53 CST  19h left      Tue 2019-07-30 06:20:52 CST  4h 20min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
n/a                          n/a           n/a                          n/a          snapd.refresh.timer
n/a                          n/a           n/a                          n/a          snapd.snap-repair.timer      snapd.snap-repair.service
n/a                          n/a           n/a                          n/a          ureadahead-stop.timer        ureadahead-stop.service
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the only custom timer working on the system? Could you also add the output of `systemctl list-timers`?

Comment: Hi @Fanatique, I updated my question. It is the only custom timer. But there are system timer  shows by `list-timers`. Could it be influenced by those system timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for this effect could be that systemd has a default setting which stops services if they are restarted too often within a certain time interval. This is controlled by the StartLimitBurst and StartLimitInterval settings. (e.g. see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422933/confusing-systemd-behaviour-with-onfailure-and-restart) and [here](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/02/18/linux-systemd-s-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-for-xxx-service/) for a discussion). An indication for this is a status message like this

> test.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

In cases where this occurs you can see this message in the service status or systemd journal file

`journalctl -b`
`systemctl status your.service`

Another issue might be the syntax of the `ExecStart=` directive in the service unit file. According to the systemd.service [man pages](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) redirection is not supported the way you used it.

> Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.

and

> Note that shell command lines are not directly supported. If shell command lines are to be used, they need to be passed explicitly to a shell implementation of some kind.

This modified .service unit file worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with systemd 237

```
[Unit]  
Description=my description  
StartLimitBurst=0  

[Service]  
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/date >> /tmp/testtimer.log'
```

I didn't change your .timer unit file except for replacing WantedBy=basic.target (didn't test if that really makes a difference compared to multi-user.target).

It was only a quick test where I started the timer manually. Haven't checked the behaviour on reboot.

**Edit**
Please note that as of systemd 232 there has been changes. Most notably, for the case at hand, the `StartLimitIntervalSec` (previously called 'StartLimitInterval') and `StartLimitBurst` options should now be placed in the [Unit] section and not in the [Service] section of the service unit file.